# How to narrow down with the mysql like clause

Tags: mysql

I run the command `select * from victims where fname like '%a%' or address like '%194%';` and i get this

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
| id | fname   | mname   | lname   | gender | address            | email      | card |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
|  1 | Ryan    | Anthony | O'Keefe | M      | 194 lou Lane | ryan@songoda.com   | 2543 |
|  3 | Beau    | Jacob   | Diddly  | M      | 21 fake cr         | elmo@q.com      | 6264 |
|  4 | Anthony | Quinn   | Jims    | M      | 34 lol lane        | chicks@hotmail.com | 3456 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+
```

for that result i would like only number 1 to show because that is the only one that contains both a in the first name and 194 in the address. Can someone point out what im doing wrong?

Comment: "that is the only one that contains both a in the first name and 194 in the address" - you said it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from victims where fname like '%a%' or address like '%194%';
```

should be

```
select * from victims where fname like '%a%' AND address like '%194%';
```

you could also take the modulus off the front if you want the first name to start with A

```
select * from victims where fname like 'a%' AND address like '194%';
```

Comment: Im running bigger querys such as

`WHERE 'gender' LIKE '%a%' OR fname LIKE '%a%' OR mname LIKE '%a%' OR lname LIKE '%a%' OR address LIKE '%a%' OR card LIKE '%a%' OR email LIKE '%a%' OR fname LIKE '%194%' OR mname LIKE '%194%' OR lname LIKE '%194%' OR address LIKE '%194%' OR card LIKE '%194%' OR email LIKE '%194%' OR fname LIKE '%5%' OR mname LIKE '%5%' OR lname LIKE '%5%' OR address LIKE '%5%' OR card LIKE '%5%' OR email LIKE '%5%'`

not all of them are hits but i want the one that has the most to either be at the top or be the only one

Comment: sounds rather convoluted, according to your question this is probably the answer. Perhaps you should've put that in the question if there is other criteria to meet.

Comment: Your right i just thought i could get help for my real problem. im sorry i couldnt explain better

Comment: if you want help for that problem write a new question with the criteria you need to meet. I will surely help you there, and many others. :)

Comment: @user3586203 I just added to this questino